# How to change method return types in order to manage errors and exceptions

Tags: scala, exception, design-patterns, error-handling, monads

The following code is in a library (I can't edit it).

```
trait ATraitInALibraryICantEdit[T] {
  def save(data: T): Future[T]
  // ....
}
```

Then, in my code, I have :

```
class MyClass[T] extends ATraitInALibraryICantEdit[T] {
  override def save(data: T): Future[T] = {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is simple inheritance. But, in my case, I would like to change the signature of the method to something like (to manage exceptions) :

```
// Type change : Future[T] --> Future[Either[String, T]]
override def save(data: T): Future[Either[String, T]] = {
  // ...
}
```

To sum up, my problem is how to change return type of a method in order to adapt it to my way of managing errors.

I guess, I should use a pattern (and not direct inheritance), but I don't know witch one. I don't even kwnow if it's possible without updating the library.

A solution is to use exceptions, I would rather prefer to use monads instead.

Comment: does your Class is used directly by you in your code or by the library ?

Comment: If library uses your code, it won't handle the `Either` anyway. If you call this code, don't use library, or add a method `saveE` that has signature you need, it can for example use the original `save` method and recover the exception to `Either`. Also note that `Future` already has a notion of error handling, as result is either `Success(res)` or `Failure(ex)`. You can see `Future` as a monad (more or less, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454798/is-future-in-scala-a-monad )

Comment: As a general comment, if you need to reuse an external library's method, you of course cannot change it, but you can wrap it with your own (I'm not a big fan of design pattern namings but I believe this one should be "decorator pattern"). Your method calls the library method and decorates it in a certain way, such as wrapping the return value in an Either. Is that what you need? I don't see a need for anything super-complicated here (perhaps I'm missing some requirements)

Comment: as @slouc said, you need wrap the calls to the external library, and adapt it to your way of doing things. This is called, wait for it, the Adapter pattern.

Comment: [bthuillier] I had the 2 cases. [Łukasz] Thanks for the Future tip. It can be a bypass in my case. [slouc & dbugger] Yes, but If the method is used by the library, you cannot change it return type, can you ? In the flow you will have a loss of information. (ie : if you give Either[String, String] and the method needs Option[String], you will loose the left of the either)
**To conclude I think that if the class is used directly in the code, the solution may be to use a pattern. On the other case (if it used by a lib), usage of future error managment is bypass. Do you agree ?**