# How to express the following nested futures with for-comprehension

Tags: scala, for-loop, dictionary, future, flatmap

My question: is it possible to simplify this nested expression with  for-comprehension ?

```
run(dbAction).flatMap(insertedJobs => {
  Future.sequence(insertedJobs.map { job =>
    recordingBean.findStreamsForInterval(job.mediaSource, job.begin, job.end) map { stream =>
      if (stream.nonEmpty) {
        recordingBean.findRecordingLocationsForInterval(stream.head.stream, job.begin, job.end).map(recordingLocations =>
          recordingLocations.map(_.size.getOrElse(0L)).sum).flatMap { expectedSizeInBytes =>
          updateSize(job.id.get, expectedSizeInBytes)
        }
        job
      } else {
        job
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: You better show the types of your methods or simplify your question. In this form you hardly get any answer

Comment: Are you sure this code works??

Comment: You have mis-matching parenthesis. Its impossible to predict what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comprehensions are powerful but they are not an almighty nesting-killer you think they are.

`for-comprehension` are useful till you are not mixing `SeqLike` monads with `non-SeqLike` monads. But once you mix them, you are back to nesting world. And it will be even worse than before because for-comprehensions hide away the details.

Lets take some examples,

```
val listOfListOfInt = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4))

val listOfInt = for {
  loi <- listOfListOfInt
  i <- loi
} yield i + 4

// This will work just fine
// listOfInt: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8)
```

Now lets mix `List` with `Future`,

```
val futureOfList = Future({ List(1, 2, 3) })

val iWillNotCompile = for {
  l <- futureOfList
  i <- list
} yield i + 4

// the above is equivalent to writing,
val iWillNotCompile = futureOfList.flatMap(l => l.map(i => i + 4))

// would have been following but does not make sense
// `Success(5, 6, 7)`
```

The above code will not compile and actually it should not compile. As `Future` is a `non-SeqLike` monad. I mean, if the above code worked it would have been a `Success(5, 6, 7)`, which does not make sense.

Similarly, following code will not work

```
val listOfFuture = List(Future({ 1 }), Future({ 2 }), Future({ 3 }) )

val iWillNotCompile = for {
  f <- listOfFuture
  i <- f
} yield i + 4

// this is equivalent to
val iWillNotCompile = listOfFuture.flatMap(f => f.map(i => i + 4)

// should have been following and it makes sense
// List(Success(5), Success(6), Success(7))
```

This case is a lot different from the previous one, as it confirms to common sense but still it will not work. The reason is that `SeqLike-Monads` and `Future`s have very very different implementations of `flatMap` and `flatten` and `map`.

So... if are dealing with a mix of `List`, `Future`, `Option`, `Try` etc, stay away from `for-comprehension`. Just try to write your code in a more clever way.

Comment: To expand: Futures actually aren't Monads. They only have monad-like properties. This has a good discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454798/is-future-in-scala-a-monad

Comment: Yes. Mathematically Scala `Future`s can violate the monad definition because they allow side effects. But the whole pure-monad discussion belongs to pure functional programming where side-effects are treated as a mortal sin. So if a functional purist uses `Future`s he won't use side-effects and hence `Future`s won't violate monad laws.

Comment: is it possible some how express Future{}.map(a => a.map(b => b)) end so on, using some kind of syntactic sugar ?

Comment: @SlowHarry `Syntactic Sugar` is exactly what I am advising you to avoid. The problem with syntactic sugars is that these have implementations which are a mix of generic + special handling for some cases. And Scala syntactic sugars have a reputation of being unpredictable (have too many special cases). Remember that magical code is not the most easily understood code.