# Why future has side effects?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am reading the book [FPiS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290653) and on the page 107 the author says:

> We should note that Future doesn’t have a purely functional interface.
>   This is part of the reason why we don’t want users of our library to
>   deal with Future directly. But importantly, even though methods on
>   Future rely on side effects, our entire Par API remains pure. It’s
>   only after the user calls run and the implementation receives an
>   ExecutorService that we expose the Future machinery. Our users
>   therefore program to a pure interface whose implementation
>   nevertheless relies on effects at the end of the day. But since our
>   API remains pure, these effects aren’t side effects.

Why Future has not purely functional interface?

Comment: I would really suspect that this question related to the debate "is Future a monad Or not"  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454798/is-future-in-scala-a-monad

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that creating a Future that induces a side-effect is in itself also a side-effect, due to Future's eager nature.

This breaks referential transparency. I.e. if you create a Future that only prints to the console, the future will be run immediately and run the side-effect without you asking it to.

An example:

```
for {
  x <- Future { println("Foo") }
  y <- Future { println("Foo") }
} yield ()
```

This results in "Foo" being printed twice. Now if `Future` was referentially transparent we should be able to get the same result in the non-inlined version below:

```
val printFuture = Future { println("Foo") }

for {
  x <- printFuture
  y <- printFuture
} yield ()
```

However, this instead prints "Foo" only once and even more problematic, it prints it no matter if you include the `for-expression` or not.

With referentially transparent expression we should be able to inline any expression without changing the semantics of the program, Future can not guarantee this, therefore it breaks referential transparency and is inherently effectful.

Comment: I don't see how this is specific to the future. Isn't it true about any expression that executes a function? If you give it a lambda with a side effect, it'll have a side effect ... (Duh!) :) Like ... I dunno ... `Seq(1,2,3).filter { println _; true }` Does that make `Seq` not purely functional too?

Comment: That is true, indeed. But most often that's how `Future` is used. If you use `Future` with a pure computation, then it should be considered referentially transparent. However, most people do not use it that way. If you compare it to the Monix task or the FS2 Task, it guarantees referential transparency for values that can capture side effects. I.e. if you try to do the same with `Task` both code snippets will behave the same way :)

Comment: Ok ... can you explain what exactly is better about `Task` then? I mean, you can inline `val task = Task delay { prinltn("foo") }`, ok, but `task.run` is still not referentially transparent. Isn't this simply pushing the problem one step down?

Comment: Yup, it is indeed! Functional Programming is all about pushing the side effects to the edge of the program! :) Have a look at this article: http://typelevel.org/blog/2017/05/02/io-monad-for-cats.html

Comment: This is a poor reason to say Future is side effecting, since if that where true, you'd need to say ALL functions in scala is side effects. Just because you can call side effecting functions inside it, it does not mean that it itself side effecting.

Comment: Well it's about referential Transparency. `Task` captures side-effects in a referential transparent way, while `Future` does not. :)

Comment: This is because you made the `printFuture` as a `Value` It's evaluated even before getting into for-comprehension. You should make `printFuture` as a function instead to get the same effect. i.e) def printFuture = Future { println("Foo") }

Comment: yes, but Future type still remains not referentially transparent. Defining the call in a function is just a hack to workaround the problem.

Answer (score 10):

A basic premise of FP is [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). In other words, avoiding side effects.

What's a side effect? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)):

> In computer science, a function or expression is said to have a **side effect** if it modifies some state outside its scope or has an observable interaction with its calling functions or the outside world. (Except, by convention, returning a value: returning a value has an effect on the calling function, but this is usually not considered as a side effect.)

And what is a Scala future? From the [documentation page](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html):

> A Future is a placeholder object for a value that may not yet exist.

So a future can transition from a not-yet-existing-value to an existing-value without any interaction from or with the rest of the program, and, as you quoted: "methods on Future rely on side effects."

It would appear that Scala futures do not maintain referential transparency.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, `Future` runs its computation automatically when it's created. Even if it lacks side-effects in its nested computation, it still breaks `flatMap` composition rule, because it changes state over time:

```
someFuture.flatMap(Future(_)) == someFuture // can be false
```

Equality implementation questions aside, we can have a race condition here: new `Future` immediately runs for a tiny fraction of time, and its `isCompleted` can differ from `someFuture` if it is already done.

In order to be pure w.r.t. effect it represents, `Future` should defer its computation and run it only when explicitly asked for it, like in the case of `Par` (or `scalaz`'s `Task`).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although, `Task` is still side effecting as far as i know, just at an explicitly asked point. I'm not sure if you can practically do this without side-effecting. Of Course you can chanin computation, but if you are not side effecting, you need to block at some point, which is rather undesirable.

Comment: Not that it's a big problem, however - the intended place to run your `Task` in a FP program is in its entry point, and that should be the last thing you actually do there. That's exactly how all the parts of the program can stay composable, including I/O operations - they're assembled into general execution plan to be run at the very end.

Comment: Fair point! Is there any good library that implements something like task, without the baggage of scalaz?

Comment: I don't really know what exactly the 'baggage' of `scalaz` everyone talking about is (mathematical naming is pretty standard and not Haskell-specific), but there's relatively new Monix library that seems to do the same thing: https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html

Comment: Thanks! I don't mean it as baggage regarding the quality of it, but it's size and scope is huge, i would not want to include it in my relatively small library (right now it does not have any runtime dependencies, besides scala)

Comment: It's not just monads, `f.map(identity) == f` is broken too. As I explained in my answer `map` (usually) creates a subscription and entirely new `Future`

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other points and explain relationship between referential transparency (a requirement) and side-effects (mutation that might break this requirement), here is kinda simplistic but pragmatic view on what's happening:

- newly created `Future` immediately submits a `Callable` task into your pool's queue. Given that queue is a mutable collection - this is basically a side-effect
- any subscription (from `onComplete` to `map`) does the same + uses an additional mutable collection of subscribers per `Callable`.

*Btw, subscriptions are not only in violation of Monad laws as noted by @P.Frolov (for `flatMap`) - Functor laws `f.map(identity) == f` are broken too. Especially, in the light of fact that newly created `Future` (by `map`) isn't equivalent to original - it has its separate subscriptions and `Callable`*

This "fire and subscribe" allows you to do stuff like:

```
val f = Future{...}
val f2 = f.map(...)
val f3 = f.map(...)//twice or more
```

Every line of this code produces a side-effect that might potentially break referential transparency and actually does as many mentioned.

The reason why many authors prefer "referential transparency" term is probably because from low-level perspective we always do some side-effects, however only subset (usually a more high-level one) of those actually makes your code "non-functional".

---

As per the futures, breaking referential transparency is most disruptive as it also leads to non-determinism (in `Future`s case):

```
val f1 = Future {
  println("1")
}

val f2 = Future {
  println("2")
}
```

It gets worse when this is combined with Monads, including `for`-comprehension cases mentioned by @Luka Jacobowitz. In practice, monads are used not only to `flatten-merge` compatible containers, but also in order to guarantee [con]sequential relation. This is probably because even in abstract algebra Monads are generalizing over consequence operators meant as a general characterization of the notion of deduction.

This simply means that it's hard to **reason** about non-deterministic logic, even harder than just non-referential-transparent stuff:

- analyzing logs produced by `Futures`, or even worse actors, is a hell. Even no matter how many labels and thread-local propagation you have - everything breaks eventually.
- non-deterministic (aka "sometimes appearing") bugs are most annoying and stay in production for years(!) - even extensive high-load testing (including performance tests) doesn't always catch those.

So, even in absence of other criteria, code that is easier to reason about, is essentially more functional and `Future`s often lead to code that isn't.

P.S. As a conclusion, if your project is tolerant to scalaz/cats/monix/fs2 so on, it's better to use Tasks/Streams/Iteratees. Those libraries introduce some risks of overdesgn of course; however, IMO it's better to spent time simplifying incomprehensible scalaz-code than debugging an incomprehensible bug.