# How to make this function pure

Tags: scala, functional-programming, purely-functional

My understanding about pure functions are that the output of the function only depends on the input. And they are referentially transparent.

But then there are side effects that happens in our code. Below is an example

```
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  case class Customer(fName: String, lName: String)
  case class Order(orderId: Int, item: String, quantity: Int)
  case class Shipment(shipmentId: Int, orderId: Int, address: String)

  trait CustomerRepo {
    def findCustomer(userId: String): Future[Customer] = ???
    def findLastOrder(customer: Customer): Future[Order] = ???
    def findShipment(orderId: Int): Future[Shipment] = ???
  }

  class ShoppingApp(customerRepo: CustomerRepo) {

    def getLastShipment(userId: String): Future[Shipment] = {
      for {
        customer <- customerRepo.findCustomer(userId)
        lastOrder <- customerRepo.findLastOrder(customer)
        shipment <- customerRepo.findShipment(lastOrder.orderId)
      } yield shipment
    }

  }
```

Above is a basic example where we do multiple side effects (call to database).

getLastShipment returns a Future. Does that makes is a pure function.

If getLastShipment is not pure then how to make it pure???

Comment: There is nothing impure about `getLastShipment`. The only "problem" is that you're using `Future`, which is eagerly evaluated and breaks RT. Other than that, you're good.

Comment: Futures work against the whole pure thing. Other than this I think to be pure the `getLastShipment` function should not depend on the context which means that it should explicitly require  `CustomerRepo `  as a function parameter.

Comment: Additionally: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3zofjl/why_is_future_totally_unusable/

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close, you're already on the right path using `Monad`s and `for-comprehensions`, however, `Future` is fundamentally side-effecting, because it does not suspend its evaluation. (For further information, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196088/why-future-has-side-effects/44196745#44196745).
If you switch your function to use something like `cats.effect.IO`:

```
def getLastShipment(userId: String): IO[Shipment] = {
  for {
    customer <- customerRepo.findCustomer(userId)
    lastOrder <- customerRepo.findLastOrder(customer)
    shipment <- customerRepo.findShipment(lastOrder.orderId)
  } yield shipment
}
```

Then this code is completely pure and referentially transparent.

Comment: Thanks @luka-jacobowit for your reply.

What I understood from this is if we put a side-effect in a container (Options, Future - ok it is not perfect, Functors etc). This will make my method getLastShipment pure...

I am just struggling to understand that how putting side-effect in a container make it pure..

Maybe can you point me to some material on that....

Thanks

Comment: Sure @abhishek, maybe this article can help you https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/04/28/monadic-io-laziness-makes-you-free.html :)