# scala exception handling with series of dependent future and non-future method calls

Tags: scala, future

I have a method that may return `Future` - successful or failed or can even throw an exception. I can avoid this by putting try catch block on entire method and return Future all the time but i would like to avoid it for now. I have few problems with calling such method:

1) In caller code, if I use `map` I expect execution of a method and expect a Future or an exception which I tried to handle in following manner:

```
object ETLCoordinator {      

  private def getBusinessListFromModules(modulePaths: Iterable[File]) : Future[String] = {
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    println("Inside getBusinessListFromModules..")
    throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("failed to get businesses") //Exception is thrown before future was constructed
    Future("ok")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("Inside Future Test..")
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    val modulePaths = Iterable(new File("mdrqaint/MDR/QAINT/QAINTX"))

    val fut1 = getBusinessListFromModules(modulePaths) //This is outside of try and which should be okay
    try { 
      fut1.map { res =>
        println("things after Successful fut1")
      }.recover{
        case t: Throwable => println("Failed future in fut1: "+ t.getMessage)
      }  
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable => println("Exception in fut1: "+ t.getMessage)
    }
  }    
}
```

Output: ( No execution of recover or catch block above)

```
Inside Future Test..
Inside getBusinessListFromModules..
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to get businesses
```

But if I put `val fut1 = getBusinessListFromModules(modulePaths)` inside Try block then Exception is get caught in Catch block and I get output:

```
Inside Future Test..
Inside getBusinessListFromModules..
Exception in fut1: failed to get businesses
```

Why is this? I though Future execution happens upon calling some of its methods like map, flatmap, onSuccess, onComplete etc. In this case call to `map` is already inside Try block.

2) What is the better way to define and call such methods? Try/catch block in a caller or try/catch in method itself? or any other way. I tried wrapping the calling method in Future so I get Future[Future[String]] in caller. I was able to avoid all try-catch.

```
val fut1 = Future(getBusinessListFromModules(modulePaths))
//try {
  fut1.map { res =>
    res.map{ str =>
      println("things after Successful fut1")  
    }.recover{
      case t: Throwable => println("Failed in future of fut1: "+ t.getMessage)
    } 
    println("things after Successful fut1 wrapper")
  }.recover{
    case t: Throwable => println("Failed to create future in fut1: "+ t.getMessage)
  }
```

3) If there is another method inbetween which does delegation to `getBusinessListFromModules` but it itself is non-future method.

```
object ETLController {

  private def getBusinessListFromModules(modulePaths: Iterable[File]) : Future[String] = {
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    println("Inside getBusinessListFromModules..")
    //throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("failed to get businesses")
    Future("ok")
  }

  private def callGetBusList(modulePaths: Iterable[File]) : String = {

    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    val etlF = getBusinessListFromModules(modulePaths)    

    etlF onComplete { 
      case Success(itr) => {
        println("Future getBusinessListFromModules success: "+ itr)
        throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("RTE from callGetBusList")
      }
      case Failure(t) => {
        println("Future getBusinessListFromModules throws an error")
      }
    }

    "callGetBusList was a success"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("Inside Future Test..")
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    val modulePaths = Iterable(new File("mdrqaint/MDR/QAINT/QAINTX"))
    try {
      val fut = Future(callGetBusList(modulePaths))
      fut.map { res =>
        println("successful future!")
      }.recover{
        case t: Throwable => println("Failed future: "+ t.getMessage)
      }
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable =>   println("callGetBusList failed:" + t.getMessage)
    }

  }    
}
```

Output: (no recover or catch block execution!)

```
Inside Future Test..
Inside getBusinessListFromModules..
Future getBusinessListFromModules success: ok
java.lang.RuntimeException: RTE from callGetBusList
    at ..
successful future!
```

I even try double wrapping Future calls :

```
val fut = Future(Future(callGetBusList(modulePaths)))
fut.map { res =>
  res.map { str =>
    println("successful inner future! "+ str)
  }.recover{
    case t: Throwable => println("Failed inner future: "+ t.getMessage)
  }
  println("successful outer future!")
}.recover{
  case t: Throwable => println("Failed outer future: "+ t.getMessage)
}
```

Output:

```
Future getBusinessListFromModules success: ok
java.lang.RuntimeException: RTE from callGetBusList
    at 
successful inner future! callGetBusList was a success
successful outer future!
```

I get "callGetBusList was a success" which seems like `RuntimeException`  inside `onComplete` method got lost! How do I catch it in a final caller? What are the better practice to handle such future dependencies?

UPDATE:
based on @dk14 explanation, Opted to convert middle method to return Future and basically all methods to return some kind of Future and not a plain Exception.

```
object ETLController {

  private def getBusinessListFromModules(modulePaths: Iterable[File]) : Future[String] = {
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    println("Inside getBusinessListFromModules..")
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("failed to get businesses")
      "ok"
    }
  }

  private def callGetBusList(modulePaths: Iterable[File]) : Future[String] = {

    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    val etlF = getBusinessListFromModules(modulePaths)    

    etlF map { itr => 
        println("Future getBusinessListFromModules success: "+ itr)
        throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("RTE from callGetBusList")
      } recover {
      case t: Throwable => {
        println("Future callGetBusList throws an error: " + t.getMessage)
        throw t
      }
    }    
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("Inside Future Test..")
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    val modulePaths = Iterable(new File("mdrqaint/MDR/QAINT/QAINTX"))
    val fut = callGetBusList(modulePaths)
    fut.map { str =>
        println("successful  future! "+ str)
    }.recover{
      case t: Throwable => println("Failed  future: "+ t.getMessage)
    }
    println("Active threads: " +Thread.activeCount())
    sys.allThreads().foreach(t => t.join())

  }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Futures are firing eagerly and they [aren't referentially transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196088/why-future-has-side-effects).
Answers to the referenced question also contain some insights about `Future`'s **internal behavior**, so I'd like to skip it here.

In order to manage side-effects concerning execution pools/queues/threads in a more predictable way, you could consider [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)/[monix](https://monix.io/)/[fs2](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) `Task` or [iteratee](https://github.com/travisbrown/iteratee)/scalaz/cats `Eval` (more abstract lazy evaluation, and intended for sync stuff) + [`Cont`](https://github.com/danslapman/cats-conts) (continuations are abstracting over subscriptions) as alternative. All are referentially transparent and start execution lazily "on-demand".

2) The best way is the one you don't like: to not throw exception outisde of Future context.

You might also consider `flatMap` to avoid `Future[Future[T]]`

3) Double wrapping Futures directly a-la `Future(Future(...))` doesn't change anything. Your method is executed on `val etlF = g...` (in the same thread) no matter what it returns. `Future("ok")`'s content (lambda) is executed eagerly (with "small" unpredictable delay) on a different thread but [execution task is being submitted to the pool] still inside `getBusinessListFromModules`.

One workaround (not really recommended) is `val etlF = Future(getBusinessListFromModules(...)).flatMap(identity)` which would return you a future wrapping any exception coming directly from `getBusinessListFromModules` and indirectly from `getBusinessListFromModules`'s internal `Future`.

It's better to refactor `getBusinessListFromModules` itself however, also introduce different exception types for different kinds of trouble (validation, sync vs async, so on) your method might get into.

P.S. There are ways to mix async and sync exception handling, but in practice it's hard to analyze and predict such mixed behavior (which you probably noticed already). And code gets ugly.

Comment: So a method that is supposed to return some kind of future, throws an exception even before it get chance to compose future then caller of that method would have no idea how to deal with it. map and recover won't work for that exception, right? So why would scala even allow that? Caller would have to wrap future calls with try/catch in those scenario.

Comment: @nir it's a long story, but mostly related to Java-legacy and compatibility. Scala (Haskell and other type-safe) way even for regular exception handling is to use `Try`/`Either` avoiding "side-effectful" `throw` at all costs. Future kinda has embedded `Try` - that's why I recommended to use it over unpredictable exception falling out of your method.

Comment: @nir  [Boring stuff:] Comparing with Java, `Try`/`Either` are kinda like checked exceptions where `Try` is used for "defects" and Either for "incorrect conditions" (truly checked). It's just Java prefers unchecked exceptions, which historically (and unintentionally) inspired by "Spring Framework", they had best intentions but as usual a lot of people just stopped writing `throws` in method signature completely. So similarly to `Option vs null` problem scala has to maintain Java-style exceptions for compatibility (even dotty, but they at least introduced union types syntax for convenience)

Comment: @nir more info about unchecked exceptions in Java: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129. And here are some [critics](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/why-should-you-use-unchecked-exceptions.html) giving all the arguments except type-safety.

Comment: I did like unchecked exception style for while when using "Spring Framework". with scala looks like even that is not preferred over `Try`, `Option` or `Either`.