# Lifting A Future using EitherT.liftF When Value Is Already a Future

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a value like this:

```scala
val ss: Option[Future[List[Either[Error, File]]]]
```

And what I want to do is to lift this to an `EitherT.liftF[Future, Error, List[Either[Error, File]]]` so what I did was this:

```scala
    ss match {
      case Some(value) => EitherT.liftF[Future, Error, List[Either[Error, File]]](value)
      case None        => EitherT.leftT[Future, List[Either[Error, File]]](Error("failed"))
    }
```

My question is whether it is correct that I can use EitherT.liftF to lift a value which is already a future because I think normally that is used for values which need to be lifted to a future, not one which is a future itself.

Comment: Yeah that is correct, that is the use of `EitherT.liftF` - check the docs:https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/EitherT$.html#liftF[F[_],A,B](fb:F[B])(implicitF:cats.Functor[F]):cats.data.EitherT[F,A,B]

Comment: Well a **Future** is not even cancelable in the first place... but being honest. no idea if using specifically a **Future** with **EitherT** can be problematic, I have never used futures in real code.

Answer (score 0):

`Future` has a `Monad` instance for practical reasons but isn't really lawful. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454798/is-future-in-scala-a-monad) on the topic.

However it will still behave as expected in many cases such as yours.

You can also implement it this way:

```scala
EitherT(ss.toRight(Error("failed")).sequence)
```