EitherT with Scala type alias
Try to use type alias with EitherT get compilation error
type FuEiErr[T] = Future[Either[Error, T]]
type FuEiErrInt = Future[Either[Error, Int]]

case class Error(msg: String)
def fA(x:Int): FuEiErr[Int] = Future(Right(x))  // compile error
def fB(x:Int): FuEiErr[Int] = Future(Right(x))  
// def fA(x:Int): FuEiErrInt = Future(Right(x)) // ok
// def fB(x:Int): FuEiErrInt = Future(Right(x)) 

@main def TestEitherT(): Unit = 
  (for {
    a  <- EitherT(fA(7))
    b  <- EitherT(fB(42))
  } yield { (b) }).value.map {
    case Left(err)  => println(s"Error: ${err.msg}")
    case Right(res) => println(s"Result: ${res}")
  }

Got error "No given instance of type cats.Functor[F] was found for parameter F of method map in class EitherT
where: F is a type variable with constraint >: [X0] =>> scala.concurrent.Future[Either[Error, X0]] scala.concurrent.Future[X0] and <: [_] =>> Any
Thanks for help!

Just for the record, EitherT is usually a bad idea and using cats with Future is a bad idea as well.

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez just curious, why? :)

@DmytroMitin a lot of reasons really, typed errors are IMHO a bad idea most of the time. EitherT doesn't play well with concurrency. cats makes zero guarantees about Future execution order, especially with traverse and especially when combined with EitherT. Is all just a mix for a disaster. IME is way simpler to just stick to concrete IO and use the failure channel or custom ADTs.

Well, heavily use EitherT in playframework environment (client and server side), so far no problems. Future is much easier to use than IO, don't need pure functionality, cancelability, ... Having already a bunch of libraries to manage (+ migration from Scala/Playframework 2 -> 3), don't want to pay the price for additional dependency and complexity with cats effect (or ZIO).

@RobertJo well if you want to use Future cool, do what you prefer. But don't mix it with cats, it will cause you trouble. Unless you don't care at all about the execution behaviour of your operations, at that point then don't use Future at all in any case.

Just for the record, the latest release of cats broke traverse for Future (again): https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/4617 - These are the kind of thing I was referring to when I said using Futures with cats was a bad idea - C.C. @DmytroMitin

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for the link. Yeah, Future is not actually a monad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454798/is-future-in-scala-a-monad Maybe instances should be in Alleycats.

@DmytroMitin yeah I already tried to do that, but is a hard and somewhat sensitive topic: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/4182 ; we at least managed to soft-deprecate them in the docs: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/4190 - TL;DR; I am in a crusade of telling every folk I see that uses cats with Future to stop :p

Just type parameters were not inferred. Try
for {
  a <- EitherT[Future, Error, Int](fA(7))
  b <- EitherT[Future, Error, Int](fB(42))
}


Yeah if you check this scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/W8Ai5HhZTXGbStcXgqSlSw/18 you can see the inferred type for a is something very weird like EitherT[[X] =>> Future[Either[Error, X] | X], Error, Int] which is what then fails the summon for the Functor. - This seems to be a bug / regression in the compiler, since this works in Scala 2: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/W8Ai5HhZTXGbStcXgqSlSw/24 my advice for @RobertoJo would be to open a ticket about it
